# Git bash keeps auto scrolling to the bottom of the window

Tags: windows, git, bash, scroll, git-bash

I have installed multiple versions of git for windows, but every version I have tried so far acts the same. If I have a bunch of output lines in the terminal, scroll up to see some of the earlier outputs, the window will automatically take me back to the bottom at the prompt. It seems to be happening on an interval about 5 seconds apart. I tried replicating the issue with CMD and powershell, but it only happens in git bash. Even just running bash.exe inside the bin folder doesn't produce the auto scrolling, just git-bash.exe. Any ideas why this is happening or how to stop it?

Edit1: It seems as though it is automatically executing a page down command. If I use the less command, it automatically goes page by page. I thought maybe it was a keyboard issue but this is the only application that seems to be doing this.

Edit2: I wrote a quick bash script that logs input to a file.

```
while true; do
    read -s -n 1 input
    echo $input >> file.txt
done
```

I printed the contents of the file using od -c file.txt. The output after a few seconds is below.

```
0000000  \n  \n 177  \n  \n 177  \n  \n 177  \n  \n 177  \n  \n  \n 177
0000020  \n  \n 177  \n  \n 177  \n  \n
0000030
```

Does anyone know how to stop it? Does this look like a keyboard issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Git Bash:

`Options ► Mouse ► uncheck "Copy on select"`

In order to make up for not having the copy on select functionality:

`Options ► Keys ► Ctl+Shift+letter shortcut`

Should allow you to use Ctl+Shift+C for copying.

Obviously this is just a workaround.  I was in the process of searching to see if a bug has been created for this issue when I found this post.

Edit: For completeness, I'm using git version 2.10.1.windows.1

Answer (score 0):

I have noted this behavior from Git Bash when the window size is smaller than some multiple of the font height. Making the window taller or the font smaller seems to fix it.